# Wrap a Model instance field

Tags: python, marshmallow

I have a model instance which has an attribute called parent which is a string containing the parent's id.

When I serialise this instance, I want to wrap the parent id so that it appears as follows:

```
{
  name = "John"
  parent = {"id": "123-345"}
}
```

What is the correct way to do this in marshmallow?

This is what I am currently doing:

```
class IdSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.String()

    @pre_dump
    def wrap(self, data, **_):
        return {"id": data}


class UserSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.String()
    parent = fields.Nested(IdSchema)
```

Answer (score -1):

const jsonString = JSON.stringify(userObject);
console.log(jsonString);